# XEP-0077: In-Band Registration

Tags: xmpp, registration

i am a newbie for xmpp. i plan to start a 'chat' web application.at client,i prepare use 'Strophe',but i found strophe cannot support registeration module.

someone said can use 'XEP-0077: In-Band Registration'.can u tell me what i can do it?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XEP-0077](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0077.html) is the way to go here.  Make sure you've read it thoroughly.  Next, look at the [strophejs-plugins](https://github.com/metajack/strophejs-plugins) project to get some examples of how to write a strophe plugin.  Then, you'll want to create protocol that imlements XEP-0077, starting with something like:

```
Strophe.addConnectionPlugin('register', {
    _connection: null,

    init: function(conn) {
        this._connection = conn;
        Strophe.addNamespace('REGISTER', 'jabber:iq:register');
    },
    get: function(callback) {
        var stanza = $iq({type: "get"}).c("query",
                                          {xmlns: Strophe.NS.REGISTER});
        return this._connection.sendIQ(stanza.tree(), callback, function(){});
    }
});
```

Make sure to contribute your patch to strophejs-plugins back on github.

Comment: hi joe. another question:in my 'chat' web app,i want to record the 'round count'(person A sends a msg "hello B" to person B,B received the msg and sends a message to reply ,just a 'round') on my web server's DB when two person is chating,but i have no idea about it.Could u give me some advice?

Comment: That's a completely different question.  Start a new one, but please give a lot more detail about *why* you're trying to do this, so it's easier for folks to answer.